# R to find the time duration

Tags: r, lubridate

I have used the library `lubridate` to find the difference between the start time and end time. Here is my code:

```
library(lubridate)

a <- read.csv("C:/Users/Desktop/Dump.csv")

b <- a$StartTime 
c <- a$EndTime

hm(c)- hm(b)
```

This is my result for the code:

```
   [1] "1H -18M 0S" "1H 5M 0S"   "1H 16M 0S"  "1H 16M 0S"  "1H 5M 0S"   "1H 16M 0S"  "1H 18M 0S" 
   [8] "44M 0S"     "1H 0M 0S"   "1H 23M 0S"  "2H -41M 0S" "1H -18M 0S" "1H -18M 0S" "1H -16M 0S"
  [15] "1H 0M 0S"   "41M 0S"     "1H 0M 0S"   "24M 0S"     "1H -20M 0S" "1H 0M 0S"   "1H -19M 0S"
  [22] "1H 16M 0S"  "1H 25M 0S"  "1H 10M 0S"  "1H 16M 0S"  "44M 0S"     "1H 18M 0S"  "1H 23M 0S" 
  [29] "1H -19M 0S" "1H 6M 0S"   "1H 16M 0S"  "1H -19M 0S" "1H -17M 0S" "1H -20M 0S" "1H 0M 0S"  
  [36] "2H -40M 0S" "2H -40M 0S" "1H -20M 0S" "1H -20M 0S" "1H 5M 0S"   "1H 17M 0S"  "1H 11M 0S" 
  [43] "1H -23M 0S" "1H -30M 0S" "1H -29M 0S" "1H -19M 0S" "45M 0S"     "1H -19M 0S" "1H 1M 0S"  
  [50] "1H -6M 0S"  "30M 0S"     "1H 28M 0S"  "1H -21M 0S" "30M 0S"     "1H 1M 0S"   "1H -10M 0S"
  [57] "1H 0M 0S"   "1H -28M 0S" "42M 0S"     "51M 0S"     "52M 0S"     "1H 17M 0S"  "2H -43M 0S"
  [64] "1H -19M 0S" "1H 1M 0S"   "1H -26M 0S" "50M 0S"     "1H -19M 0S" "1H 0M 0S"   "1H -23M 0S"
  [71] "1H 2M 0S"   "40M 0S"     "30M 0S"     "1H -15M 0S" "1H -6M 0S"  "30M 0S"     "1H -33M 0S"
  [78] "1H -20M 0S" "1H 4M 0S"   "41M 0S"     "1H 13M 0S"  "1H 0M 0S"   "1H 0M 0S"   "1H -30M 0S"
  [85] "29M 0S"     "1H 10M 0S"  "1H 5M 0S"   "1H 0M 0S"   "1H -27M 0S" "51M 0S"     "1H -5M 0S" 
  [92] "31M 0S"     "1H -30M 0S" "33M 0S"     "1H 0M 0S"   "36M 0S"     "2H -43M 0S" "1H -30M 0S"
  [99] "34M 0S"     "50M 0S"     "1H -31M 0S" "41M 0S"     "50M 0S"     "1H -15M 0S" "1H -15M 0S"
```

This is my result but it has negative in the mins, which means the correct answer is the "hour - mins". Anyone know where is my code is wrong or did I forget to code anything.

The format for the data is factor.

Comment: It might be useful to include the format of the input, so can you include the output from `dput(head(a,n=20))`? There might be other ways to get what you need (with or without `lubridate`).

Answer (score 0):

You probably have database of time of signals (code given does not reproduce this kind of results). Nevertheless, try calculate elapsed time (time2 - time3 or time2%--%time3) and the use duration to have in proper format

```
time2 <- c("12:23:11", "09:45:31", "12:05:22")
time3 <- c("2:14", "2:16", "3:35")
time2 <- hms(time2)
## [1] "12H 23M 11S" "9H 45M 31S"  "12H 5M 22S"
time3 <- hm(time3)
## [1] "2H 14M 0S" "2H 16M 0S" "3H 35M 0S"
elapsed.time <- time2 - time3
as.duration(elapsed.time)
```

Comment: I take format from your example , which was hms (hours/ minutes/ seconds). Any format if fine once you specify it with as.Data in lubridate, so then you can properly define duration.